# Uninstalled pre-commit preventing 'git commit' (pipenv)

Tags: python-3.x, pipenv, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I recently uninstalled pre-commit from my environment. I performed the following in pipenv:

```
pipenv --rm
<deleted Pipfile and Pipfile.lock>
pipenv install -r requirements.txt
```

I ensured that the pre-commit module was no longer in the requirements.txt. When I make a git commit I get:

```
~/my_project/.venv/bin/python: No module named pre_commit
```

This is preventing me from committing, and I have no idea where this is coming from, since pre-commit is not being installed. Further, the traceback path specified is pointing to python and not python3. What am I missing?

Comment: I suppose its called in your pre-commit hook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are still `pre-commit` hooks installed in your `git` repository. You can remove them by simply deleting `.git/hooks/pre-commit` in you repository, after which `pre-commit` won't be called anymore when commiting.

Comment: thanks, that was it. I just deleted two files with 'rm pre-commit*' in .git/hooks/

Comment: I have a new repo without hooks and I still can't commit. Sorry, this is bad by design that upon uninstalling all dependent hooks are still active

Answer (score 15):

typically the way to remove the hook installed by `pre-commit install` is to call `pre-commit uninstall` -- though if you've removed `pre-commit` from your system you can remove the hook scripts manually

you can usually find them by doing:

```
grep pre-commit.com .git/hooks/*
```

as that marker is listed [in the hook files](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/blob/354b900f15e88a06ce8493e0316c288c44777017/pre_commit/resources/hook-tmpl#L2)

from there you can delete them:

```
grep -l pre-commit.com .git/hooks/* | xargs rm
```

---

disclaimer: I made pre-commit